# mysql utf-8 charset support

Tags: mysql, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

i want ti have fully unicode database via mysql. i hear about using `SET NAMES 'utf8'` is not good for some SQL injection issue.

what's the best usage mysql for fully unicode support.

Comment: Huh? That sounds like a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

We often use `utf8_general_ci` as table collation in mysql databases.  It's faster but it is considered a legacy collation.  The [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) recommends `utf8_unicode_ci` for most precise character resolution. As for the sql injection: you need to escape with `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead of `addslashes()`, the latter won't prevent sql injection in unicode tables.

Comment: ... or even better, use PDO with parametrized queries instead of the old `mysql_*` functions.